# Should we rename the "requests" tag into "making-requests"?

Tags: discussion, tags, specific-tag

I recently discovered that we have a [requests](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/requests) for when the OP need to request something from someone else.

When I talked about it in chat, someone got confused and thought that the tag was for "I have a request for IPS, please answer my question". This person then suggested to rename [requests](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/requests) for [making-requests](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/making-requests) which will match your other tag like [saying-no](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/saying-no), [making-friends](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/making-friends), etc...

So, do you think we should rename this tag? And, more generally, do you think we should rename tags so that they end in "-ing" if possible (obviously won't work for tags like [family](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/family),[autism-spectrum](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/autism-spectrum), etc...)?

Comment: You're beginning a tag crusade! :p

Comment: @avazula Yeap, that's my new hobby :P

Comment: Also, this confusion should be cleared up in the tag excerpt and de tag usage guidelines. I personally think that [tag:requests] is much clearer than [tag:requesting].

Comment: @JAD I edited, is that still understandable? Also, you might want to write an answer instead of a comment

Comment: If, for some reason we do want our tags to follow a verb-ing format, may I suggest [tag:making-requests] instead?

Comment: @JAD Nice, I like your idea!

Comment: I still don't think we *should*, but I really dislike `requesting` as a word/tag. It just sounds weird.

Comment: I would second [tag:making-requests] over [tag:requesting].  Requesting is... weird.  It's not verbage that is used very often, so I think 'making requests' sounds a bit more natural and intuitive.  Especially when comparing to a tag like [tag:making-friends], this seems acceptable.

Comment: @JessK. since I agree,I edited accordingly